# How to mimic the iOS 7 camera

Tags: ios7, camera, avcapturesession

I am creating a camera app, hoping to have similar look as iOS 7's built-in camera app, and adding a few more custom buttons. I am following example of UIImagePickerControllerDelegate but it does not fit my purpose because I want the first screen showing the view (i.e. same as iOS' camera). The UIImagePicker requires user to press a button to bring up the camera mode. I have a feeling that I should follow AVCaptureSession but I am lost in the lengthly documentation (I'm a Rookie). Can anyone show me a high-level step, or any sample source code will be highly appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you already guessed, `UIImagePickerController` has limited functionality and may not fit your needs. For an `AVCaptureSession` example, take a look at these (referenced 10th Feb 2014):

- https://github.com/romyilano/AVFoundationCameraExamples/tree/master/Simple
- http://www.ios-developer.net/iphone-ipad-programmer/development/camera/record-video-with-avcapturesession-2